# How to convert the whole desktop to monochrome?

Tags: windows, graphics, hook

Does modern Windows provide some sort of hooks that would allow a developer to change pixel values before they reach the GPU/are sent to the display?

For example to convert the whole desktop to monochrome independent of the applications currenly displayed (perhaps even including games).

Something that could work along side an existing (closed source) display driver.

Comment: Apply greyscale color filter? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4344736/windows-10-use-color-filters

Comment: I'm looking for a way to programatically perform any type of filter.